# Inference problem: "...referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer"

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I reduced an issue I hit today into this minimal example. ([playground link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJSIN4BQixiMYqATsAIYQqIBiccAPACoB8+RJvUAngAcUALkQByAELUK4nsQC+BeYlCRYCRGBQAPKE1adMMKGIPsO2M8wvdevCiiggKSEyqUqANk9XNrrBgUZADmXAA+iOAAJijAZCjRiAC8+MhCohLSsohKvADuABYwPoiYwMyIAITJqTFxCdG4hPYkAPRtiGwZpGDAKI6Q9AMUcBSIhQP0AEYgUF0AyhPUaMiTiBBjjtC9-YN0iEUoSIVwAG4DoYjnA1q6+swqvJtgGHd6Ke8PcOXMuE8kCpwT7aD4dDZwAC2kOOsDAITWMFWcDmiEhKwA1qsoOskWgQCgPAQFEA))

```
function test() {
    interface Foo<T> {
        type: 'Bar'
    }

    function nextFoo<T>(it: Foo<T>): Foo<T> {
        return it
    }

    let foo: Foo<string> | undefined = { type: 'Bar' }
    while (foo !== undefined) {
        // Type inference error here but TS has the correct inference when hovering over nextFoo
        const next = nextFoo(foo) 
        foo = next // commenting this out masks the issue
    }
}
```

This seems like something that TypeScript should be able to handle. When I hover over `nextFoo` in vscode it does look like it correctly infers the type there. Something about setting `foo` to `next` while it can potentially be `undefined` results in this.

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: The compiler sees that the type of `next` depends on the type of `foo` which apparently depends on the type of `next` (because assigning `next` to `foo` will reset any control-flow narrowing).  An explicit type annotation of `const next: Foo<string> = ` will fix it.  I think this is essentially the same issue as in [microsoft/TypeScript#1146](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1146).

Comment: @jcalz I don't understand why the type inference of `foo` depends on `next` though. It's already explicitly set right? It doesn't matter what I assign to foo anywhere (to a human), the type won't be different than the type that I declared it as. I also can't understand that explanation in the context of being able to fix this by removing the `| undefined` from the `foo` type. That also solves the issue without having to type `next` so something else has to be going on somewhere.

Comment: Control flow analysis happens when testing or assigning to values of a union type.  So `foo = next`, where the declared type of `foo` is a union type, has implications for the apparent type of `foo`. Which means that the compiler's graph of dependencies for type inference will show that the type of `foo` depends on the type of `next`.  Obviously a human being would be able to just "see" what the types should be, but the compiler uses a particular algorithm which apparently detects circularity.  Should I write this up as an answer or is there something I'm still missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah I think this is turning into a good answer. What I'm taking away from this is that its a side effect of the compiler implementation when dealing with type inference involving union types. I don't know if I should consider it a bug or not. Naively, it seems like something that could be short circuited under conditions with specified types, or just circumvented all together by not trying to infer types through a graph when types are hard coded, as is the case with the `foo` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could strongly type your `next` variable:

```
function test() {
    interface Foo<T> {
        type: 'Bar'
    }

    function nextFoo<T>(it: Foo<T>): Foo<T> {
        return it
    }

    let foo: Foo<string> | undefined = { type: 'Bar' }
    while (foo !== undefined) {
        // Type inference error here but TS has the correct inference when hovering over nextFoo
        const next: Foo<string> | undefined = nextFoo(foo) 
        foo = next // commenting this out masks the issue
    }
}
```

Comment: `const next: typeof foo = nextFoo(foo)` also works, and is a bit neater imo.

Comment: @ConnorLow love it!